# what does this ''(const vector<vector<int> > &A)" segment of code mean?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm facing some issue in understanding the following segment of code
`(const vector<vector<int> > &A)`. Will it define a 2D array?

Comment: In C++2a that should become [(`std::span<const std::vector<int>>` A)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Comment: More or less, it's a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

`const vector<vector<int> > &A` means that `A` is a `const` reference to a `vector` of `vector`s of `int`egers.

Comment: You never explain ``&``A

Comment: @deoncagadoes I believe I did. `&` is what makes it a reference.